# How to add AMRnb codec to pjsip and sipek?

Tags: codec, pjsip, amr

I want to add AMR nb codec to pjsip.
I download pjsip project from it's site in vs2012, and I have a amrNB project in vs2012, but how to add this project to pjsip?

I need amrnb with rtpmap=122. 
When I follow steps of [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Using-OpenCORE-AMR-NB-WB-Codec#no1), AMR with rtpmap=105  added to my project, but I need rtpmap=122.